# Почему в CLion переменная выводится два раза?

Tags: c++, clion

Установил студ версию `CLion` — хочется после `PyCharm`-а потестить и IDE для  любимого `с++`. Запустил стандартный "helloworld" — всё норм: MinGW найден, всё работает. Но когда идёт запрос ввода переменной через `cin` и вывод через `cout`, переменная выводится два раза. Закомментил вывод, но после ввода переменной всё равно выводит значение.

Как это пофиксить? Что я делаю неправильно?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3):

Ты передаешь параметры в исполняемый файл не на напрямую, а через консоль Clion. Как только ввод в консоль окончен, Clion передает эти параметры приложению.

Теперь пример. Код приложения:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   int buf1;
   int buf2;

   cin >> buf1 >> buf2;
   system("pause");

   cout << buf1 <<" " << buf2 << endl;
   system("pause");

   return 0;
}
```

1. Через командную строку Windows

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

2. Через консоль Clion из под Windows

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

3. Через консоль Clion из под Unix подобной системы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При каждом запуске передаем параметром строку "1 2 3 4", чтобы посмотреть что будет записано в переменных. Как видишь, только Clion из под Windows продублировала значения. Как мне кажется, такое поведение связано особенностью ввода параметров в консоль операционной системы, а не среды.

Answer (score 0):

Эту «фичу» CLion с дублированием вывода в консоль можно отключить следующим образом:

В главном меню переходим в `Help` и кликаем на `Edit Custom Properties`.
CLion предложит создать файл idea.properties - соглашайтесь. В открывшемся файле добавляем конфигурационный параметр:

```
run.processes.with.pty = false
```

Перезапустите CLion. Всё, я вас категорически поздравляю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]